# Prometheus - see current value of metric having label in python

Tags: python, prometheus

```
from prometheus_client import Counter
processed = Counter('messages_processed', 'total messages processed', ["kafka_topic"])
processed.lables(topic()).inc()     # Increment by 1
```

How can I get the value(print on console in python), so as to test if its working or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution. This can be acheived by specifying the label using `labels()` and then using `_value.get()` to get its value

```
processed.labels(msg.topic())._value.get())
```

Comment: did not work for me

Comment: You need to change `msg.topic()` to something specific. For me, it gives the kafka topic.